# Invitation mail to group member when added via https://groups.google.com/ cf AdminDirectory.Members.insert

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk

When adding a new memer to a group via https://groups.google.com/ an invitation mail is sent. When adding a new member via the AdminSDK API (AdminDirectory.Members.insert) no invitation mail is sent. Is there any parameter to AdminDirectory.Members.insert I miss?

Comment: You did not miss anything. It is not possible to send mail invitation through Directory API when adding a member to a group

Comment: OK thanks for the fast reply. Thats bad. I also noticed that adding members via the Admin Console does not provide the option of invitation mail either